# Index of loop not working properlly

Tags: jquery, ajax, for-loop

I was trying to get an array from a JSON file and i noticed that everytime i got it it was on a different order. After some research i discovered the issue:

My variable **i** (loop index) get's random values once it gets on the 2nd getJSON.

```
$.getJSON('*******',
    function(data) {

        for(var i=0;i<data['****'].length;i++){             
            console.log('1:'+i);
            (function(i){
                console.log('\n');
                $.getJSON('**********',
                function(data2) {                       
                    console.log('2:'+i);
                }); 

            })(i);
        }           
});
```

On the first console.log it show the numbers from 0 to 128 in the right way. The problem is that when it goes to the second console.log it shows something like:

70 to 128 and then 0 to 70

On other posts people were said that including (function(i){ })(i) should solve this problem, but it didnt work on my code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete shot in the dark but try ...

```
                     $.getJSON('*******',
        function(data) {

            for(var i=0;i<data['****'].length;i++){             
                console.log('1:'+i);
                (function(j){
                    console.log('\n');
                    $.getJSON('**********',
                    function(data2) {                       
                        console.log('2:'+j);
                    }); 

                })(i);
            }           
        });
```

That will shield your inner function from having to deal with the passed in value and the global value. (note that I changed the i to j in the section function.